# Resharper ToString Format Completion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

In the Reshaper 8.1 the new `ToString()` Format Completion is great, but for DateTime all the options seem to be in America culture, e.g. month/ day /year, being in Australia this is not very useful is there any way you can change the default completion options so that day/month/year and day-month-year could be added or replace the current list of formats,

If not how can I turn off only the datetime `toString` code completion  ?

Comment: You can't. The formats are hardcoded in EN-us. Create a feature request [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP)

Comment: The formats are hardcoded to the invariant culture, not en-US. Although, since MS is an American company, I don't think there's too much difference :)

Comment: This feature sucks if you want to create a non-standard ToString. I'm having a lot of trouble with it. It keeps changing it and I can't quite figure out how to stop it *"Correcting"* me. Seriously guys if your going to create feature this invasive give us the ability to turn it off!

Comment: This is a terrible feature, and only slows productivity and can lead to multiple unwanted mistakes (I ended up with several datetime format string errors after just quickly modying them without noticing the format completion change - which triggered without enter being pressed).

Answer (score 2):

The `ToString` completion items are formatted using the invariant culture, which means `DateTime` comes out as `MM/dd/yyyy`. This can't be changed, and the `ToString` completion items can't be removed or disabled.

As @python_kaa says, you can file a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP. It would be useful if you could provide an example of how you'd expect it to work. The complexity is for ReSharper to figure out which culture it should use - it will be very hard to know from context what culture to use (if it's passed in, what value is it? What's the ambient culture of the running code? It could be running on another machine, or a server executing a web request. Or should it just always be the UI culture of the code editor?)

Comment: Just an option to let each user set the options manually would be great, there's no need for intelligence to figure something out, at least imho.